# Buildozer error when trying to take a .py, .kv and .mp3 into an .apk for android

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Im trying to get my python project to an APK using Buildozer, it crashes with a big ass error an I dont know how to fix it.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

import psutil
import os

Builder.load_file('main.kv')

Window.size = (400, 600)

class myLayout(BoxLayout):
    slide_text = ObjectProperty(None)
    user_limit = 0  # Initialize user_limit
    sound = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load("mySound.mp3")
        if not self.sound:
            print("Error loading sound")

    def slide_it(self, *args):
        self.slide_text.text = str(int(args[1]))
        self.user_limit = int(args[1])  # Update user_limit

    def submit_button_pressed(self):
        battery_slider = self.ids.battery_slider
        user_limit = battery_slider.value
        print("User selected battery limit:", user_limit)
        self.user_limit = user_limit  # Update user_limit with the selected value

        battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
        plugged = battery.power_plugged
        plugged = "Plugged In" if plugged else "Not Plugged In"

        if battery.percent >= self.user_limit and plugged == "Plugged In":
            if self.sound:
                self.sound.play()

class BatteryPrototypeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = BatteryPrototypeApp()
    app.run()
```

The main.kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.2.1

<myLayout>:
    slide_text: slider_label
    orientation: "vertical"

    Label:
        id: slider_label
        text: "Escoge el limite de bateria!"
        font_size: 30

    Label:
        id: current_value_label
        text: f"Current value: {battery_slider.value:.0f}"  # Show current value of slider
        font_size: 20

    Slider:
        id: battery_slider
        min: 70
        max: 100
        step: 1
        orientation: "horizontal"
        padding: 50
        on_value: root.slide_it(*args)

    Button:
        text: "Submit"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "200dp"
        font_size: 32
        on_release: root.submit_button_pressed()
```

The app itself works as intended but the problem is getting it into an APK

---

This is the Buildozer.spec file. I've removed commented parameters in this post because I got flagged for spam

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = BatteryAlarm

# (str) Package name
package.name = batteryalarm

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.yoruumicode

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,txt,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = images/*.png




# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1



# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,pillow



#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Novfensec Inc.

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.11.4

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.2.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
android.presplash_color = black



# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, BATTERY_STATS, REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS





#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false




[buildozer]
```

I've researched a lot, tried different things but still same error:

```
  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=batteryalarm', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy==2.2.1,kivymd==0.104.2,pillow==8.3.1', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/mnt/c/users/ryevk/desktop/alarm-main/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'DESKTOP-6SS9QAL'
#     PWD = '/mnt/c/users/ryevk/desktop/alarm-main'
#     LOGNAME = 'yoruumi'
#     HOME = '/home/yoruumi'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'yoruumi'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/yoruumi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/yoruumi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2204.2.33.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Eclipse '
 'Adoptium/jdk-8.0.372.7-hotspot/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Eclipse '
 'Adoptium/jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Users/Ryevk/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Ryevk/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
 'VS '
 'Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Ryevk/.dotnet/tools:/mnt/c/Users/Ryevk/Desktop/BatteryAlarm:/snap/bin')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/yoruumi'
#     _ = '/home/yoruumi/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/yoruumi/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/yoruumi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/yoruumi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```